# How to create sub task to a task using SP Designer 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I would like to create a sub task to a task using SP Designer 2010 workflow? thanks in advance

Comment: You means to say,you have to add child task inside Parent task.

Comment: Exactly, need to create child task

Comment: are you using task for approval process

Comment: No, its just assigning task to person to complete